# AngularJS: Getting Started

Tags: angularjs

So I am trying to emulate the example "Hello !" given on the Angular website here: http://angularjs.org/ under the section **The Basics**.

I have placed the following file in my my-user-name directory which contains the `angular.js` directory that is installed when you clone the Angular repo as per the site's instructions.

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app>
<head>
    <script src='js/angular-1.0.0rc6.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" ng-nmodel="name">
    <h2>Hello {{name}}!</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

I am running the angular server via `grunt webserver`which I run from my home directory path and access the above html file by typing `http://localhost:8000/angular.html` But I get a blank page. I realize that the path `js/angular-1.0.0rc6.js` doesn't mean anything in the context of my home directory in that there is no `js` directory in my home dir and similarly no `angular-1.0.0rc6.js` lying anywhere around those environs. I just copied that path-name from the example. What is the standard protocol in terms of where the script files are located relative to where you develop your angular apps?

Thank you!

Comment: FYI: I got the above html from the youtube video under the Basics section, not the one on the actual page.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uFTFsKmkQnQ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's so many possibilities that I'd nudge you in a slightly different direction to get started.  Check out Yeoman (http://yeoman.io).

Yeoman is a nice way to learn because, after running it (which just takes typing 'yo angular' on the command line once Yeoman is installed), it **gets you started with a small working app that you can experiment with and it scaffolds up a nice overall base (code/test scaffold, tools, ...) to build from.**   And it even uses grunt, as you did, to launch your app (you'll just type `grunt server` and your app should appear in a browser (with live reload working - which is a cool time saver).

Yeoman should save you from having to figure out the kinds of things you are now- is my file in the right location?  is my server pointing to the right place?  etc...  All taken care of by yeoman.

Here's a tutorial showing how to install Yeoman and install Angular:  http://www.sitepoint.com/kickstart-your-angularjs-development-with-yeoman-grunt-and-bower/

You'll see it's only a handful of commands.

In case you'd like to dive in more, here's a talk posted by the Angular team about using Yeoman with Angular: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XOmwZopzcTA